# How to run simple functions in visual studio without creating form

Tags: vb.net

I know this is kind of a rookie question, but how do you run short, simple vb.net functions in visual studio without creating a form? I'm currently working on homework problems and want to double check my answers by inputting them into visual studio but can't seem to figure out how to do so.

This is what I'm trying to run, for example:

```
 Dim num as Integer = 30 

 If num > 20 Then 
     num -= 10
 If num < 20 Then 
     num *= 2 
 Else
     num /= 2 
 End if 
 Else 
 If num > 10 Then
    num += 2
 End If 
 End If 
 DisplayTextBox.Text = CStr(num)
```

Comment: Good idea to check your answers. Turn on Option Strict. This will point out potential problems at design time that can produce exceptions at runtime. For example `n /= 2` returns a double (division does not necessary come out to a whole number) and n is declared as an Integer.

Comment: If you call `Console.WriteLine` then you'll see the specified text written to the Ouput window in VS.  If you use `Debug.WriteLine` then you can even leave the code in and it will be excluded when compiling a Release build, where `Console.WriteLine` will be included in a Release build too. The user wouldn't notice it in normal use but it would be there.  Just note that the result of `Debug.WriteLine` doesn't always appear as immediately as that of `Console.WriteLine`. To get the best of both worlds you can use conditional compilation.

Comment: Perhaps you should look into Unit testing? It's a couple of extra steps, but if you put your code in (a) separate method(s) you can use it to perform different tests and verify the results with the [`Assert`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assert?view=mstest-net-1.2.0#methods) methods. You can also define multiple/different tests for different parts of your code.

Comment: I had some trouble finding a good introduction to Unit Testing, but at last I managed to find this: https://stackify.com/unit-testing-basics-best-practices/ - it's in C#, but the practices are the same in VB. It describes the basics of how you can write and run tests for your code.

Answer (score 1):

To do simple checks of functions I tend to use a console application. However DisplayTextBox.Text object is part of a forms application so I would use the console for output

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim num As Integer = 30
        If num > 20 Then
            num -= 10
            If num < 20 Then
                num *= 2
            Else
                num /= 2
            End If
        Else
            If num > 10 Then
                num += 2
            End If
        End If
        Console.WriteLine(num)
    End Sub
End Module
```

**EDIT Added link**

[Making a console Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/quickstart-visual-basic-console?view=vs-2017)

Answer (score 0):

This is a great opportunity to explore using classes and writing unit tests, because this is how we would write code and verify that it works in real-world setting. For this sort of scenario I often just do all of my work in a unit test project.

In Visual Studio, add a new project and select Visual Basic > Test > Unit Test Project (.NET Standard or .NET Core, whichever you're working with.)

A first step is to modify your code so that it receives an input instead of setting the value for `num`. And then modify it so that it returns a value instead of displaying it on a form.

```
Module Module1
    Function DoSomethingWithNumber(num As Integer) as Integer
        If num > 20 Then
            num -= 10
            If num < 20 Then
                num *= 2
            Else
                num /= 2
            End If
        Else
            If num > 10 Then
                num += 2
            End If
        End If
        Return num
    End Function
End Module
```

This is closer to how we would normally write code anyway. We don't want the part that performs a calculation to also display it on a form, because what happens if we want the same logic but we don't want to display it on a form?

Also, displaying it on a form makes it harder or impossible to write a unit test, and part of writing good code is writing code for which we can write unit tests.

Now you can test the function by calling it, passing in different values, and verifying that the result is what you expect. To do that, create a unit test class, like this:

```
<TestClass>
Public Class MyUnitTests
    <TestMethod>
    Sub DoesSomethingWithNumber_DoesRightThingWithNumberGreaterThan20()
        Dim input As Integer = 21
        Dim output = Module1.DoSomethingWithNumber(input)
        Assert.AreEqual(22, output)
    End Sub

    <TestMethod>
    Sub DoesSomethingWithNumber_DoesRightThingWithNumberLessThan10()
        Dim input As Integer = 5
        Dim output = Module1.DoSomethingWithNumber(input)
        Assert.AreEqual(input, output)
    End Sub
End Class
```

It's obvious from the names and the values that I don't really know what your code is supposed to do. The point is that you would give the test methods names that describe the condition you're testing. Then you would "assert" that the output is what you expect it to be.

Then, from the Test menu, select Run > All tests.

The Test Explorer window will show you which tests passed and which failed. If the test asserts that you should have a certain value but your function returned something else, the test will fail. Now you know that your code doesn't do what you want it to do. You can right-click on the test and debug it with breakpoints, or just read the code and see if you can find the problem.

What's great about these is that you can have tests for multiple conditions. So if you fix the code to account for one expected result but in the process you break something else, the tests will tell you. You've succeeded when all of your tests pass.

This is how we write code on the job (hopefully.) Some people write tests first. Some write the code and then write tests. But by doing this we know that our code does what we expect it to. The tests also describe what the code is supposed to do. If someone else makes changes they can run the tests and know that they didn't break anything.

Finally, learning to write unit tests for our code improves the quality of the code that we write. It steers us toward writing simpler code and following other best practices.